# Caracteres Duplos em Expressões Regulares

Tags: javascript

Estou treinando meu javascript e estou querendo saber como eu procuro caracteres repetidos em uma expressão regular

Exemplo: Eu digito aa em uma textbox e, dentro de um método de validação, o método verifica se o caracter a, digitado duas vezes seguidas, está dentro da RegExp

Comment: Aceite a resposta se ela resolve seu problema :)

Answer (score 4):

O que você quer fazer precisaria de algo chamado **backreference** (http://www.regular-expressions.info/backref.html), onde se referência um grupo anteriormente capturado dentro da expressão regular. Teria essa cara:

```
(.)\1
```

Ou seja:

- `(.)` Dê match em qualquer caractere e crie um grupo
- `\1` Encontre o caractere que você acabou de encontrar de novo

Você pode misturar isso com `+` ou os ranges de repetição `{min,max}` para fazer qualquer match:

```
(.)\1{2,4}
```

- `(.)` Mesmo de acima
- `\1{2,4}` Dê match em 3 a 5 caracteres repetidos

Ou:

```
(.)\1{2}
```

- `(.)` Mesmo de acima
- `\1{2}` Dê match em exatamente 2 caracteres repetidos

Ou:

```
(.)\1+
```

- `(.)` Mesmo de acima
- `\1+` Dê match em 2 ou mais caracteres repetidos

---

Se quiser ser mais específico (está procurando só por repetições de caracteres tipo espaço, por exemplo), é só alterar o grupo `(.)` para o que gostaria de encontrar repetido.

---

Em código:

```
function hasRepetition(str) {
  return /(.)\1/.test(str);
}

hasRepetition('best') // false
hasRepetition('beest') // true
```